# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in On line 96

Tags: php, class

I have a class Notification.

However, this does not work at all. 
The public function deleteNotification. Will not work on line 96. 
I already have. Public function, public static function and static function. 
But none of them work.

Who can see my way to help with this. Thanks! 
Sorry for my bad english

```
<?php


class Notification {  

    /**
     * Config
     *
     * @access private 
     */ 
    private static $config;

    /**
     * Database
     *
     * @access private 
     */     
    private $db;

    /**
     * Session
     *
     * @access private 
     */     
    private $session;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @access public 
     */   
    public function __construct() {

        self::$config = config_load('notification');

        $this->db = new Database();
        $this->session = new Session();


    }


   var $type;  
   var $to_user;  
   var $from_user;  
   var $reference;  
   var $timestamp;  
   var $newcount;  

    /**
     * getAllNotifications
     * 
     * @access public 
     */   
   public function getAllNotifications() {  
     $this->newcount = Notification::newCount($this->to_user);  
        foreach ($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " .
            self::$config['table_notification'] .
            " WHERE to_user = 1 ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 10") as $row) {

            $result[] = array(
                'id'         =>$row['id'],
                'to_user'    =>$row['to_user'],
                'from_user'  =>$row['from_user'],
                'reference'  =>$row['reference'],
                'type'       =>$row['type'],
                'seen'       =>$row['seen'],
                'timestamp'  =>$row['timestamp']
            );

        }
     if ($result) {  
       return $result;  
     }  
     return false; //none found  
   } 

    /**
     * Get newCount
     * 
     * @access public 
     */   
   public function newCount($user) { 
     $row = ceil($this->db->row_count("SELECT * FROM " .
          self::$config['table_notification'] . " WHERE to_user = 1  AND seen = 0 "));
     return $row;  
   }  

    /**
     * deleteNotification
     * 
     * @access public 
     */   
    public static function deleteNotification($id) {     
    $where = array(
        'id' => $id
    );

    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->delete(self::$config['table_notification']); 
   }  

 }  
 ?>
```

`$id` is defined in this file:

update_notifications.php:

```
 <?php    
include("common.php"); 
$id = 1;  
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];  
switch($action) {  
  case "seen":  
 if (isset($_REQUEST['notifications'])) {  
   $notifications = json_decode($_REQUEST['notifications']);  
   foreach ($notifications as $notification) {  
     if (is_numeric($notification)) Notification::Seen($notification);  
   }  
 }  
 break;  
 case "delete":  
 $notification = $_REQUEST['notification'];  
 if (is_numeric($notification)) Notification::deleteNotification($notification);  
 break;  
}  
?>
```

In this file I have set `$id = 1;` on line 3 to see if it worked.
The option of worldofjr would also not work. This gives the following erorr to:

> `Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Notification::deleteNotification() must be an instance of Notification, none given, called in C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\server\htdocs\update_notifications.php on line 17 and defined in C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\server\htdocs\libraries\Notification.php on line 103`

Comment: How do you instantiate the class and call the function?

Comment: is there any error after you call the function?

Answer (score 4):

Static methods do not belong to the instance of an object, `$this` relates to the instance of the class. So, there is no `$this` in static method `deleteNotification`.

Do you really need this method to be static?

Answer (score 1):

A `static` method does not use an instance of an object, it is for related functions that use the Class.

Either remove the `static` keyword for the method or pass an instance of the class into the method using an argument.

```
public static function deleteNotification($id,Notification $n) {     
   $where = array(
       'id' => $id
   );

   $n->db->where($where);
   $n->db->delete(self::$config['table_notification']); // ??
}
```

To call this `static` method you need to provide an ID (`$id`) and an instance of `Notification` that you want to delete from.

```
deleteNotification($id,$notification);
```

Additionally, you need to write an access (and/or delete) method for `$config` in order to delete a value (where I've commented `??`).

Hope this helps.